# How to evenly distribute data in a matrix by a column?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, matrix, dataset

If I had a matrix like the one below:

```
X = [...
 1  2   3; 
 1  4   5; 
 1  6   7; 
 1  8   9; 
 0  10  11; 
 0  12  13; 
 1  14  15]
```

and I wanted to evenly distribute the contents so I had something like this where the `0s` in the first column are fairly evenly spaced throughout the dataset, but the rows stay together:

```
Y = [...
 1  2   3; 
 1  4   5; 
 0  10  11; 
 1  6   7; 
 1  8   9;  
 0  12  13; 
 1  14  15]
```

(Side note this is a made up example, I'm using a much bigger dataset)

What I mean for evenly distributed is if I were to break the dataset down, I would want the same ratio of 1s to 0s no matter where I divided the data set. So if there were 4 ones and 1 zero in the first 5 rows of data, I would want 8 ones and 2 zeros in the next 10 rows of the data.

Comment: What does “evenly distribute” mean? This is a very vague description. Is this a random shuffle? Or is there a specific definition for zeros to be spread out?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, What I mean for evenly distributed is if I were to break the dataset down, I would want the same ratio of 1s to 0s no matter where I divided the data set. So if there were 4 ones and 1 zero in the first 5 rows of data, I would want 8 ones and 2 zeros in the next 10 rows of the data.

Comment: But what if you can’t evenly divide the number of rows by the number of 0s?

Comment: It doesn't need to be exact, just spread out as well as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to move the rows randomly, you can use `randperm`:

```
Y = X(randperm(size(X, 1)), :)
```

> ```
> Y =
>
>      1     8     9
>      0    12    13
>      1    14    15
>      1     4     5
>      0    10    11
>      1     2     3
>      1     6     7
> ```

Although 0s and 1s can be expected to be distributed almost evenly if there are a large number of rows, this is not guaranteed.

They can only be spread evenly if the number of 0s and 1s are equal. In this case, they can be arranged one by one:

```
X = [...
 1  2   3; 
 1  4   5; 
 0  6   7; 
 1  8   9; 
 0  10  11; 
 0  12  13; 
 1  14  15];
Y= zeros(size(X));
Y(1:2:end, :) = X(X(:, 1)==1, :);
Y(2:2:end, :) = X(X(:, 1)==0, :)
```

> ```
> Y =
>
>      1     2     3
>      0     6     7
>      1     4     5
>      0    10    11
>      1     8     9
>      0    12    13
>      1    14    15
> ```

But in your case, where the number of 0s and 1s are not equal, you can combine above methods. For example in your test case, first arrange two of 1s and two of 0s alternatively, then spread 3 remaining 1s randomly (the opposite steps have been taken to implement):

```
Y = zeros(size(X));
I0 = find(~X(:, 1));
n0 = length(I0);
I1 = find(X(:, 1));
n1 = length(I1);
nRandom = abs(n0-n1);
nAlter = min(n0, n1);

filled = randperm(size(X, 1), nRandom);
if n0 > n1
   Y(filled, :) = X(I0(nAlter+1:end), :);
else
   Y(filled, :) = X(I1(nAlter+1:end), :);
end

empty = setdiff(1:size(X, 1), filled);
Y(empty(1:2:nAlter*2), :) = X(I1(1:nAlter), :);
Y(empty(2:2:nAlter*2), :) = X(I0(1:nAlter), :)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to enforce some sort of uniformity in the distribution of subsets of data is to sort the rows (see `sortrows`), and then split the data by alternating rows. For example, to divide into 3 equal groups:

```
X = sortrows(X);
X1 = X(1:3:end,:);
X2 = X(2:3:end,:);
X3 = X(3:3:end,:);
```

This does bias the sunsets though: `X1` always has smaller values than `X2`, etc.